# Memset to set array elements to 0

Tags: c, memset

I'm a newbie playing with memset and pointers.

When I compile and run  :

```
main(){
int a;
int *b = (int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
memset(b,0, 5*sizeof(int));
if (b != NULL){
    for(a=0;a<4;a++){
        //b[a] = a*a;
        printf
        ("Value of b %u\n", b[a]);
    }   
}
free(b);
b = NULL;
}
```

I am able to print all elements value as 0. However when I change the memset line to

```
memset(b,0, sizeof(b));
```

I always get one of the elements with a huge number which I assumed to be the address of that element. However on trying to print both address and value at element with:

```
printf("Value of b %u and address %u\n", b[a], b+(a*sizeof(int)));
```

I get two long numbers which aren't the same.

What exactly is happening? Have I used memset in the wrong way? 
Please tell me if I need to attach screenshots of output/ clarify my question.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably should be using `a<5` in your `for` loop and you probably want to check for NULL _before_ the `memset`. And don't cast the return value of malloc in C. It's unnecessary and can hide subtle errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`b` is a pointer, so `sizeof(b)` is the size of a pointer, most likely 4 or 8 on current systems. So you're only setting the first few bytes to 0, instead of the entire array.

If you had declared `b` as an array, e.g.

```
int b[5];
```

then `sizeof(b)` would be the size of the entire array, and your `memset` would work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks.  But on running the  program multiple times, I always encountered only the third element to have a different value other than 0. Is it just coincidence?

Comment: Yup, but more specifically it is "undefined behavior". Sometimes you'll get correct values, sometimes you won't, sometimes the program will wash your dog for you.

Comment: @PR, no, not surprising at all. You're only setting the first few to zero, the rest are exactly as they were before the `memset`, which are arbitrary values (including possibly zero). Set `b[4] = 42` before the `memset` then examine it afterwards.